# Sum of almost-prime zeta functions. Part II

Tags: riemann-zeta

I've already asked [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3143044/sum-of-almost-prime-zeta-functions) regarding the Sum of almost-prime zeta functions. Now I'm interested in the next question, denote: $$\zeta_{k}^{al}(s, N)= \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{a(n)}{n^s},$$
where $$a_k(n)=1, \Omega(n)\leq k$$ $$a_k(n)=0, \Omega(n)>k$$

I'm interested in the following sum dependence on $N$ for big (and fixed) integer $k$:

$$Q_k(N)=\sum_{n=1}^N (1-a_k(n))$$

I gues for $N \leq e^{kln2}$ $Q_k(N)=0$, at $N \sim e^{e^k}$ the sum have  inflection point (if we  consider $N$ as a continuous variable) and for $N >> e^{e^k}$ it is constant. Is my guess correct?

Comment: From the PNT by induction $\sum_{n \le x, \Omega(n)=k} 1 \sim \frac{x}{\ln x} \frac{(\ln \ln x)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}$

Comment: @reuns,  so $Q_k(N)$ is not constant,  $Q_k(N) \sim \alpha (k) N $ as $N \rightarrow \infty$, where  $ \alpha (k) \rightarrow 0$   as $k\rightarrow \infty$ is this correct?